# Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined with data("ui-autocomplete")

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with autocomplete which is keep giving this error and I am unable to figure it out what is causing this issue. I have tried everything on so and still not able to figure it out.

I have bootstrap js and jquery ui also loaded in order of

jquery-1.11.2',
'jquery-ui',
'bootstrap'

```
$("#search-destination").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var url = "http://localhost/abc/public_html/query/visiting?";
            var data = {term: $("#search-destination").val()};
            $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
                // data is an array of objects and must be transformed for autocomplete to use
                var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data.places, function (m) {
                    var data = {
                        label: (!isEmpty(m.city)) ? m.title + " (" + m.city + ")" : m.title,
                    };
                    return data;
                });
                response(array);
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {

        },
        select: function (event, ui) {

        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var $a = $("<a></a>").text(item.label);
        highlightText(this.term, $a);
        return $("<li></li>").append($a).appendTo(ul);
    };
```